# Using LINQ's SkipWhile over string properties

Tags: linq

I have a list of strings and I want to skip all that end with the sequence _E so out of:

- Apple
- Apple_E
- Orange
- Banana

Only "Apple_E" should be omitted. This should be a simple LINQ statement, correct?

```
foreach (var fruit in fruits.SkipWhile(x => x.EndsWith("_E")) 
{
       Console.WriteLine(fruit);
}
```

Will not omit Apple_E ... am I missing something obvious here? I have also used `x.Trim().EndsWith("_E")` to make sure there wasn't dirty data for some reason. If I do this, I get the list printed as shown above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you don't mean to use `.Where()`?

```
foreach (var fruit in fruits.Where(x => !x.EndsWith("_E")))
{
       Console.WriteLine(fruit);
}
```

Comment: Ah! Well it serves me right for trying to program while watching March Madness, I spent 15 minutes on this